# Connect PC to Rpi3 using serial connexion in puTTY

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-jessie, putty, serial-console

As specified in the title, I try to connect my Rpi 3 running [Raspbian Jessie Lite from 2017-07-05](http://vx2-downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite/images/raspbian_lite-2017-07-05/2017-07-05-raspbian-jessie-lite.zip) to my Windows 10 PC using puTTY on serial mode with [this cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N4X3BJB).

I tried to follow a few tutorials which led me to put :

```
enable_uart=0
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
```

in my `/boot/config.txt` file and
remove

```
console=serial0,115200
```

from my `/boot/cmdline.txt` file.

Cables wiring according to the amazon webpage :

> Red +5V, Black GND, Green TXD, White RXD

I plugged my red cable on pin #4, black on pin #6, green on pin #8 and white on pin #10

*Pin numbers according to this image*
 [image]

Nothing appears on my puTTY window, and I become desperate.

If someone already faced the same problem or, at least, knows how to solve it, I'd be glad he helps me !

Please excuse my english, this isn't my first language.

---

Edit : The cable works fine on my Android Things Rpi3, so it's not coming from the cable

Comment: Forget whatever dodgy link you followed (which disabled BOTH Bluetooth AND serial) and enable serial from `raspi-config`. I **STRONGLY** suggest that you **DO NOT** connect the USB serial adapter 5V to the Pi 5V pins.

Comment: So I remove every edits I did and ONLY use raspi-config ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You plugged the cables wrong. You have to plug RX to TX and TX to RX. Also plug ground to ground.

Comment: Thank you, I changed it, and used only `raspi-config` as @Milliways suggested and it works !

Comment: @Maxime.D Please mark this as the accepted answer - there is a tick you need to click under the voting buttons to the left